# How to emit data in Vue after api call is finished

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a windows.addEventListener that triggers an API call. I need to pass a name from the api call to the parent component to display it as a title on a dashboard. How can I emit the data to my parent component

child:

```
 <sankey-input-details v-if="!tableLoading" :cardListData="dataFromApi"/>

    async apiData() {
            const nodeData = this.dateRange
            ? await get('nodeData', {
                dateStart: this.dateRange[0],
                dateEnd: this.dateRange[1],
                nodeName: this.nodeName
            }) : await get('nodeData', {
                nodeName: this.nodeName
              });
            nodeData[0].name <-------- data to be emitted.
            this.tableLoading = false;
```

parent:

```
props: {
    title: String,
    cardListData: Array
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, You can emit the event to parent from child by using `$emit` function.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<p>{{ childmsg }}</p>',
  mounted() {
    // Just for the demo I am emiting the value directly but you can replace that with your API call code.
    const nodeData = [{
        name: 'Parent Header'
    }];
    this.$emit('headername', nodeData[0].name);
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    headerText: null
  },
  methods: {
    showName(e) {
      this.headerText = e;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ headerText }}</h1>
  <child childmsg="This is a child component" @headername="showName"></child>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#emitting-and-listening-to-events

> The $emit() method is also available on the component instance as this.$emit():

so in your method:

```js
this.$emit('emitName', nodeData[0].name)
```